# Specifying a flag for Other Linker Flags on Podfile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, dependency-management, cocoapods

Is there a way to specify an aditional flag to `Other Linker Flags` in a Podfile with CocoaPods? I need to add `-lc++` to a Podfile with C++ files. I saw [this](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#post_install) on the Guides, but I can't get it working.

Comment: Are you sure you need it for Podfile? Most commonly it is necessary for a podspec when a pod is being developed. In case of a target project instead of specifying `Other Linker Flags` in a Podfile you can always specify it directly in a project.

Comment: Ah yes! You were right! I was thinking on using a `post_install` hook but adding that to the `podspec` on `xcconfig` makes more sense. Thanks!